# Added to Rails app on Heroku. How to setup database in local environment?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, heroku, sqlite

I was recently added to a Rails application via Heroku. I'm able to clone the app to my local machine using:

```
heroku git:clone -a appname
```

However, I have issues running local tests and other tasks related to not having a local database. The production environment uses Postgres and the development environment uses sqlite3. What's the best way to get a local database setup?

Answer (score 0):

Simply pull the production database from Heroku. Run the following once you have heroku_toolbelt and you have access to the app on Heroku:

```
heroku pg:pull DATABASE_URL app_development --app app_name_on_heroku_here
```

This will create a new database locally named "app_development" so rename it to your app. See `config/database.yml` for your development database name.

Comment: I have the toolbelt installed and I can access the app but I'm getting some permission errors while running this.

Comment: Make sure you're listed as a collaborator on the heroku app under settings.  Also, use postgres as your local database and not sqlite to avoid any compatability issues. By using the pull command above it will use postgres as long as you have it installed and it's running.

Comment: Thanks for your help here. This ended up working after I got the user information working for Postgres.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to setup the databases required for development. This can be done using the built in `rake db` tasks:

```
rake db:create
rake db:migrate
```

This should see your local database created and migrated up to the latest migration.

Answer (score 0):

As you have successfully clone rails project from Heroku and your production database is PostgreSQL which is different from your local database SQLite you should update some files from your local project

```
1. remove or comment "gem pg" and add gem 'sqlite3' and run bundle install
2. Make changes in your database.yml file 

default: &default
  adapter: sqlite3
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000

development:
  <<: *default
  database: db/development.sqlite3

3 run rake db:create
4 run rake db:migrate
5 if you have data in seed file run rake db:seed
```